# Not getting JSON data in the order in which i have entered

Tags: java, json, netbeans

I am fetching details from a database table which contains 3 rows in JAVA.
 I am using JSONarray and JSONObject as follows

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject mainjsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
```

The data from table is put to the jsonObject as follows for each one:

```
String qry="select * from details";
ResultSet res = select .executeQuery(qry);
while(res.next){

String Name=res.getString("name");
 String age=res.getString("age");

.
.

jsonObject.put("Name", Name);
jsonObject.put("age", age);

.

.

ja.put(jsonObject);

}



mainjsonObject.put("PERSONAL DETAILS",ja);
```

I should get the output json as follows(i.e. the order in which i entered):

```
{
"PERSONAL DETAILS": [
    {
      " name": "abc",
      "age": "4",
      "gender": "F",
      "Place": "abc1"
    },
    {
      " name": "xyz",
      "age": "3",
      "gender": "M",
      "Place": "abc2"
    }


]

}
```

But am getting the values in random order like below:

{

```
"PERSONAL DETAILS": [

    {



     "age": "4",
    " name": "abc",
      "Place": "abc1"
     "gender": "F",

    },

    {



   "age": "3",
  " name": "xyz",
   "Place": "abc2"
   "gender": "M",



    }


]

}
```

Please help me with a solution. I need to get all the values in the same order in which i have entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to build json object construct using LinkedHashMap and then pass it to the constructor like this ,

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> jsonOrderedMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

jsonOrderedMap.put("Name", res.getString(1));
...
...
// struct you want  

JSONObject JSONorder = new JSONObject(jsonOrderedMap);

JSONArray sortedJSON = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(JSONorder));
```

Comment: Thanks for ur kind reply @Mohideen . I wil try it out and say if it worked.

Comment: will check myself and let you know